# Static layers missing when loading a flash generated swf using swf loader in AIR

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, air

We have a Flash game which need to be loaded and played from an AIR app. 
using the swf loader, the game swf is loaded into the AIR app. But the static background layers of the swf are not appearing in the loaded game.

Those graphical elements which are generated via action script only are appearing. When we are playing it independently (outside the AIR app), it works fine.
Is there a setting that i am missing in Flash or Flex. 
we are working with Flex 4.

Comment: How do you create those layers?  Could it be a path issue to an asset?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I corrected it myself. It was a problem with the game script. conflicting of two lines of code in the timeline action.